# React update 2D array in react-sortable without flushSync

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am using [react-sortable](https://github.com/SortableJS/react-sortablejs) ([demo](http://sortablejs.github.io/Sortable/)) for my project. Intended behavior is having multiple draggable lists side-by-side, and they belong in the same group (meaning elements can be freely dragged around between each list). Since the column size is variable, I would like a 2D array state variable to store all the lists, where each row of the array corresponds to one list.

As a reference, a minimal draggable list can be defined as

```js
export const BasicFunction: FC = (props) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState<ItemType[]>([
    { id: 1, name: "shrek" },
    { id: 2, name: "fiona" },
  ]);

  return (
    <ReactSortable list={state} setList={setState}>
      {state.map((item) => (
        <div key={item.id}>{item.name}</div>
      ))}
    </ReactSortable>
  );
};
```

Note how both the state variable and the setState function need to be provided to `ReactSortable`. This means I need to generate a `setState` function for each row:

```js
type Dispatch<A> = (value: A) => void;

function setArrayRow(setFcn: Dispatch<Item[][]>, array: Item[][], idx: number): Dispatch<Item[]> {
  return (row: Item[]) => {
    let cloned = {...array};
    cloned[idx] = row;
    setFcn(cloned);
    flushSync(() => {}); // ! BAD !
  };
}

const [array, setArray] = useState<Item[][]>(init_value);

// usage:
{indices.map((rowIdx) => (
  <ReactSortable list={array[rowIdx]} setList={setArrayRow(setArray, array, rowIdx)} group="courses">
    // display the draggable list...
  </ReactSortable>
))}
```

The problem is with `flushSync`. When I drag an element from one list to another, there are two updates to the state variable: deleting the element from one row of the array and adding it to another row. Since state variables hold their original values before flushing the updates, there is a synchronization problem without `flushSync`. Example:

```
Original: [[a, b], [c, d]] - We move element "a" to second row
Row 2 adds a, attempting to change array to [[a, b], [a, c, d]]
Row 1 deletes a, attempting to change array to [[b], [c, d]]
After flush, the final array becomes [[b], [c, d]] - "a" is lost!
```

With `flushSync`, we have the classic "Warning: flushSync was called from inside a lifecycle method. React cannot flush when React is already rendering. Consider moving this call to a scheduler task or micro task".

Is there a better way to solve the problem? e.g. Only update a component instead of the whole tree, better way of creating such a state variable, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `setState()` functions have an option of passing in a function `(prevState) => currState` as the parameter, instead of just the newest value. Although the state variable itself is not updated, the value of `prevState` is guaranteed to be the newest. This is called a [functional update](https://react.dev/reference/react/Component#setstate).

`setArrayRow` can now be simplified as:

```js
function setArrayRow(setFcn: Dispatch<SetStateAction<Item[][]>>, idx: number): Dispatch<Item[]> {
  return (newRow: Item[]) => {
    setFcn((prevArray: Item[][]) => {
      let cloned = [...prevArray];
      cloned[idx] = newRow;
      return cloned;
    })
  };
}
```